# C++ class: one getter/setter for all data members?

Tags: c++, templates, getter-setter, protected

I tried to practice C++ through some OOP, and thus has class like this:

```
class Obj
{
protected:
    cls1 class1;
    cls2 class2;
    ......
    clsn classn;
}
```

I really need to make these members `protected`, I suppose. then the question becomes how can other functions invoke the class data member to retrieve/modify its value. One common solution is through getter/setter functions. But it would be cumbersome to write every getter and setter for each member. So, can I achieve one uniform getter/setter member function with template?

```
class Obj
{
    template<typename T> int get_stats(){
        ...
        // maybe using is_same_v<T,cls1> to get what class of data member I attempt to access
        // thus confirm the data member to access? 
    };
    template<typename T> void add_stats();
}
```

Would that be possible, or with some other features?

Comment: Don't do this. Make them public. Really - suggest reading Bjarne himself commenting on this. It's non-idiomatic to C++ to have getters/setters when the member itself could be public.

Comment: Put the members in an array or `std::array`. Then one getter and setter (with an index parameter) works.

Comment: @john `std::tuple<>` as these are distinct classes, but yes, that might work.

Comment: @JackLee Also suggesting to take a look at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding

Comment: @lorro So they are, I somehow missed that.

Comment: It seems you have caught the "getter/setter-itis" disease. If you think you need them, you're at the wrong abstraction level.

Comment: @lorro, would you mind provide a link or post on Bjarne's comment?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, no it's not possible to do that and it would be a terrible idea to have a getter and a setter for all of your data. If you doing so, why bother put it in `protected`, just put it `public`. I'm also pretty sure that you want them `private` and not `protected`. But I don't have enough information.

When doing OOP, you don't want that the user of your class have full control of your data, you only want to expose behavior of your class through function.  Kept your data `private` and then do not write setters. Or make them public and do not write setters.

Of course sometimes, it's good to have some setters, but I speak in a general purpose

Comment: For non-recursive AggregateTypes it's possible - but we're on the same side, don't write getters/setters when you should simply expose the member.

Answer (score 0):

try to make them public
or you should make a setter and getter to every variable this is for security

Answer (score 0):

you can use friend functions and classes. they are available for doing this kind of thing. you can declare a friend class or function in the class that you want to befriend with like:

`friend class_name;` I suggest you read [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/friend-class-function-cpp/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your "template getter / setter" will do something more than return a reference / assign, then we can do something with the [`boost::pfr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_pfr.html) library.

```
template<typename T>
T & get() { 
    auto & value = std::get<T>(boost::pfr::structure_tie(*this)); 
    /* do stuff */ 
    return value; 
}

template<typename T>
const T & get() const { 
    auto & value = std::get<T>(boost::pfr::structure_tie(*this)); 
    /* do stuff */ 
    return value; 
}

template<typename T>
void set(const T & value) {
    auto & member = std::get<T>(boost::pfr::structure_tie(*this));
    /* do stuff */ 
    member = value; 
}
```

If you aren't doing anything in the `/* do stuff */`, then you may as well make these members `public`.